# G-Suite Groups - some emails from external users being sent from group address

Tags: google-workspace, google-groups, google-workspace-for-business

I have set up a Team (Internet) type group from the free edition of G-Suite.

Some of the emails that are being sent to the group are arriving in my inbox with a from address as the group (rather than the original sender's email address).  This isn't happening for all emails that are sent to the group though, only certain domains.  Is there a setting that controls this or is this a limitation of the free subscription?

I don't seem to have this issue with the paid subscription on a different domain.

Comment: Not as far as I can see.  It's one group that forwards some email as the group address and other emails as the senders address.

Comment: Your group isn't really even a Google Group , but an Admin Console group; https://support.google.com/a/answer/33329?hl=en  - Google Groups for Business is not even available on the free legacy edition of G Suite.   Do the certain affected domains include AOL or Yahoo , or any 'powered by yahoo' email domains such as ATT ?